# Laravel duplicate queries on user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The debugbar reads

`368 statements were executed, 360 of which were duplicated, 8 unique`

It turns out that with every check on my user, via `auth()->user()->isCustomer()` and other similar functions, it's actually looking up the user every time.

i.e.

```
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        // If the user has the 'admin' role, always authorize
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', 'customer')->first() !== null) {
            return true;
        }

        return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
    }
    // Check for admin
    public function isCustomer()
    {
        return $this->hasRole('customer');
    }
```

How do I safely cache this information on the user object so the database isn't being hounded every time?

I also use the `404labfr/laravel-impersonate` function on this project (so when you are an Admin, you can impersonate other users).

Comment: the guards do cache the user so its not the guards (auth) ... what ever you are doing in `isCustomer` is doing the query .. this isn't looking up the user every time you are looking up their roles every time ... use the dynamic property for the relationship to load it and use that instead of doing a new query to search through their roles

Comment: how would I do that please @lagbox

Answer (score 0):

I think you can decrease queries by half using:

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('name', ['customer', $role])->first();
}
```